# Changing the data type of a column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE PLACE(
  POSTCODE VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  STREET_NAME VARCHAR(10),
  COUNTY VARCHAR(10),
  CITY VARCHAR(10));
```

I want to change the `name`, `county` and `city` from `varchar(10)` to `varchar(20)`.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 46):

```
ALTER TABLE place
  MODIFY( street_name VARCHAR2(20),
          county      VARCHAR2(20),
          city        VARCHAR2(20) )
```

Note that I am also changing the data type from `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR2` to be more conventional.  There is no functional difference at present between the two though the behavior of `VARCHAR` may change in the future to match the SQL standard.

Comment: so VARCHAR2 will be a more better option to use

Comment: @user1232622 - `VARCHAR2` will definitely be more conventional, yes.  If you want to avoid the (admittedly small) risk that the behavior of your `VARCHAR` columns will change in a future version of Oracle in a way that breaks your application, you want to use `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: do you think you can also help me with this i have created a table but lets say i have 3 tables how can i check if that table is there and what is inside that table

Comment: @user1232622 - I'm not sure that I understand the question.  If you want to see "what is inside that table", I would assume that you want to write a `SELECT` statement against the table.  Is that what you're looking for?  Or are you asking something else?  Regardless, it probably makes sense to ask that as a separate question rather than as a comment on this answer since they appear to be independent questions.

Comment: oh ok i just wanted to know about  the select statement

Comment: everytime i try asking the questionit always says it doesn't meet our quality standard it is so annoying so can you just help me on this page

Comment: @user1232622 - That probably indicates that you need to spend some time refining your question.  Provide the background that someone would need to answer the question.  Ask the question as clearly and specifically as you can.  Make sure that you're using proper grammar and capitalization and that the code snippets you post are formatted.

Comment: i just really can't work this formatting out i must have had the same message about 20 times saying it does not meet our quality standard so can you help me how to write a question on here

Comment: @user1232622 - Are you sure that your question provides all the background someone would need to answer it?  Are you sure that you are including what you've already tried and why it didn't meet your needs?  Are you sure that the question is properly formatted, that the capitalization is correct, etc?  You've managed to ask 6 questions here already and plenty of other people are asking questions successfully so there must be something about the question you're trying to ask that is problematic.

Comment: If you want to see the definition of the table use 'desc place'

Answer (score 10):

**if you want to change only type of column use below:**

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY (<column_name> <new_Type>)
in your case:    
ALTER TABLE place MODIFY (street_name VARCHAR2(20),
                          county      VARCHAR2(20),
                          city        VARCHAR2(20))
```

If your table has data you could act below:

1. add a column with new type to table.
2. copy data from old column to new column.
3. drop old column.
4. rename new column to old.

For rename a column use below:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> rename column <column_name> to <new_column_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very general example is here to do the same -

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  COLUMN_NAME NUMBER NOT NULL,   -- Modify with varchar2(20) NOT NULL
  .
  .
  .  
);
```

Step to modify the datatype of **COLUMN_NAME** from **NUMBER** to **VARCHAR2**

**STEPS:**

```
--Step 1: Add a temp column COLUMN_NAME_TEMP in table TABLE_NAME to hold data temporary
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD( COLUMN_NAME_TEMP           varchar2(20) );

--Step 2: Update temp column COLUMN_NAME_TEMP with Old columns COLUMN_NAME data
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_NAME_TEMP   = COLUMN_NAME;

--Step 3: Remove NOT NULL constrain from old columns COLUMN_NAME
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY (COLUMN_NAME NULL);

--Step 4: Update old columns COLUMN_NAME data with NULL
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME  = NULL;

--Step 5: Alter table old columns COLUMN_NAME to new data type varchar2(20)
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY COLUMN_NAME varchar2(20);

--Step 6: Update old columns COLUMN_NAME with data from temp columns COLUMN_NAME_TEMP
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_NAME  = COLUMN_NAME_TEMP;

--Step 7: Add NOT NULL constrain from old columns [COLUMN_NAME]
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY (COLUMN_NAME NOT NULL);

--Step 8: Drop the temp column [COLUMN_NAME_TEMP]
alter table TABLE_NAME drop column COLUMN_NAME_TEMP;
```

**If *NOT NULL* constrain is not exist the omitte step-3 and step-7**

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle 10G and later

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't modify the data type of a table if you have some amount of records  already present in the table.

You have to empty the table records of the column (you want to modify the data type) first and then use the below command :

```
alter table place
modify ( street_name varchar2(20), country varchar2(20), city varchar2(20) );
```

Definitely it will work!

Comment: Oracle will allow you to modify data types on existing columns in an existing table where there is already data, as long as the existing data is compatible with the new data type.  In this case, the questioner wants to make the columns wider; certainly, that's allowed without moving data.

Comment: @MikeB can't get why downvote this answer. I just got `ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype` error on Oracle 11g and was forced to use temporal column for saving values, then drop original one and rename temporal one.

Comment: @coffman21 I think my comment above explains the way the product behaves; it isn't *always* necessary to have a column be empty in order to change its type.

Comment: @MikeB I understood that it's not *always* necessary. Still it's an open question to me *when* can I rely on the fact that Oracle won't fail running my script which, say, extends VARCHAR2(50) to VARCHAR2(255).

Answer (score -1):

```
Alter table placemodify(street name varchar2(20),city varchar2(20)
```