# pandas df.to_sql to Oracle database datatype inconsistency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

## Problem

I have a pandas dataframe and I'm trying to use the `pd.df.to_sql()` function to an Oracle database. My Oracle database is `19.3c`. Seems easy enough right? Why won't it work??

I saw in a few other another stackoverflow posts that I should be using sqlalchemy datatypes. Okay. Links:

- [Pandas and SQL Alchemy: Specify Column Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755450/pandas-and-sql-alchemy-specify-column-data-types)
- [Pandas to_sql changing datatype in database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294611/pandas-to-sql-changing-datatype-in-database-table)
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#oracle-data-types

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import NUMBER, VARCHAR2, DATE

oracle_dtypes = {
        'id' : NUMBER(38,0),
        'counts' : Integer,
        'name' : VARCHAR2(50),
        'swear_words' : String(9999)
        'date' : DATE()   
}

df_upload.to_sql(
    "oracle_table", 
    db.engine, 
    schema="SA_COVID", 
    if_exists="replace", 
    index=False
    dtype=oracle_dtypes
)
```

It never fails to convert random groups to `CLOB` or some other random datatypes. What should I do?

## Things i've tried

I've tried and didn't work...

- trucating (sending a SQL statement to the db from python) the table first then `if_exist="append"`
- using the `if_exist="replace"`
- using Oracle specific dialect of `sqlalchemy` datatypes *only*
- using the generic `sqlalchmey` datatypes *only*
- using a mix of both just bc I'm frustrated

Maybe it's an Oracle specific issue?

## Things I haven't tried:

Things I haven't tried:

- Dropping table and just recreating it before insert
- `to_sql` adhoc and the send a series of some `ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name`

Related Links:

- [Changing the data type of a column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321775/changing-the-data-type-of-a-column-in-oracle?rq=1)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: is sql alchemy creating the table for you, or are you inserting into an existing table. If the latter does the former give you an error? can you add the create table statement from Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to double check the incoming datatypes from the API into my pandas dataframe (made a dumb assumption the data was clean)... The API was yielding all strings, and using `df.info` really helped.

Needed to convert all the the integer, numeric, and dates to the appropriate datatypes in python (that was the main issue), and from there could re-map the the database datatypes. In short...

> API (all strings) --> Python (set datatypes) --> Database (map datatypes using sqlalchemy)

I used the `pd.Int64Dtype()` for integer columns with null values, and `'datetime64[ns]'` for datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when I was using `df.to_sql`

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
df_upload.to_sql(
    "oracle_table", 
    db.engine, 
    schema="SA_COVID", 
    if_exists="replace", 
    index=False
    dtype=oracle_dtypes
)
```

**Change your dtypes like this:**

```
oracle_dtypes = {
        'id' : sa.types.NUMBER(38,0),
        'counts' : sa.types.Integer,
        'name' : sa.types.VARCHAR2(50),
        'swear_words' : sa.types.String(9999)
        'date' : sa.types.DATE()   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I tried this too in my troubleshooting, but looks like my issue was something else